# How IMAP UID works when it crosses 4 billion mark?

Tags: email, imap

As mentioned in the [RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-92) the max value of `UID` assigned to each *mail* is   *"4,294,967,296 (Non-zero unsigned 32-bit integer)"*, so what would happen if that `UID` value is crossed?

I am planning to fetch emails from IMAP server based on last `UID` fetched

```
imap.fetch(`${lastUID}:*`,cb)
```

As I understand, *fetching* mails using the last `UID` logic is most inclusive way of fetching *new* or *recent* mails for all type of email accounts (Gmail, Outlook) since Gmail does not allow the use of `\Recent` flag. So what will be the case when the `UID` reaches its maximum value and how can that situation be handled?

Comment: Likely, if it were to happen (and receiving 4B emails would take a long time) it would regenerate the UIDVALIDITY and start again. But do consider even at the reasonably robust value of 10000 messages per day this would still take 1176 years.

Comment: @Max so if the `UIDVALIDITY ` changes and if I start fetching mails starting with `UID` value 1, then mails with same `UID`  before the  `UIDVALIDITY `  value change should not come, right ? I understand this case is not likely to happen but I want to understand the flow.

Comment: When the server can’t maintain UIDs for some reason, and overflowing could be a reason (along with migrating mail servers or similar), it changes the UIDVALIDITY and then it is allowed to renumber the messages.  A changed UIDVALIDITY informs the client that any cache it has is no longer valid and it would need to start again. The server is free to start from UID 1 again and renumber all the messages to remove any holes, and the client must forget everything it knows, as if the mailbox is brand new. Because of this, servers generally try very hard not to do this.